# Show the UIToolbar's UIBarButtonItem in the right side, instead of the left side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uidatepicker

Can someone tell me why my button is on the left side instead of the right? I would like it on the right. Thanks for any help you can give!

```
- (IBAction)getSelection:(id)sender {

    if(self.pickerShown == NO){

        self.slidePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 216)];
        self.slidePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
        self.slidePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.view addSubview:self.slidePicker];

        //make done button
        self.toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
        self.toolBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                             action:@selector(testButton)];

        self.toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.barButtonDone,nil];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonDone;
        self.barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        self.pickerShown = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:self.toolBar];
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to add:**

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
```

**And change:**

```
self.toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: flexSpace, self.barButtonDone,nil];
```

**I thing that you can:**

```
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonDone;
```

**Information**:

`UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` is a *blank space to add between other items. The space is distributed equally between the other items. Other item properties are ignored when this value is set.*

Apple documentation: [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also, you have the `Flexible Space Bar Button Item` in **Xcode Interface Builder**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Gaberiel. I appreciate the time you took to explain this to me. you rock!